# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 - Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, requirejs, magento-upgrade

I upgrade from magento 2.2 to 2.3.5 today, and is encounter the following error, also the checkout page shows nothing but the store header/logo area. ( the shopping cart page is ok), i think the onepage checkout is broken due to the js error?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
```

system.log

```
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amfaq_top_link' element cannot be added as child to 'header.links', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
```

debug.log

```
[2020-08-08 05:00:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://my.website.com/checkout/cart/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_2cc8e9aa1959f1494858d47270a263e562c9d271-94-final_price-USD-20200807-1-0-"}} []
[2020-08-08 05:00:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://my.website.com/checkout/cart/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_2cc8e9aa1959f1494858d47270a263e562c9d271-95-final_price-USD-20200807-1-0-"}} []
[2020-08-08 05:00:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://my.website.com/checkout/cart/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_2cc8e9aa1959f1494858d47270a263e562c9d271-96-final_price-USD-20200807-1-0-"}} []
[2020-08-08 05:00:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://my.website.com/checkout/cart/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_2cc8e9aa1959f1494858d47270a263e562c9d271-2-final_price-USD-20200807-1-0-"}} []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'amfaq_top_link' element cannot be added as child to 'header.links', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-08-08 05:01:34] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
```

Comment: Please check your log error .

Comment: i updated the question with the latest error from the logs. can you help me on this? everything works fine on 2.2.9 before upgrade to 2.3.5